# How do you resize a textarea to it's content on window load using JavaScript (MVC)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, textarea

I am making a project in MVC 5 that fills a textarea using data from a database.  I need its height to be the same as the text inside of it, to display all of the text to the user without having to scroll down.  So far I have tried the following, which doesn't seem to work:

JavaScript:

```
    function resizeText(){
        var scroll_height = $("#Remarks").get(0).scrollHeight;

        $("#Remarks").css('height', scroll_height + 'px');
    };

    window.onload = resizeText;
```

HTML:

```
    <table class="col-sm-12">
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remarks)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remarks, new { @rows = "6", @cols = "150" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remarks)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: The code works as is for me, without sending the page from MVC but creating a simple HTML page. Is the ID of the textarea getting targeted correctly? Try doing some console logs to make sure you are hitting the textarea, like dumping out the text in it.

Comment: It looks like I made a simple syntax mistake with ending parentheses on some functions.